# How do I implement a clickable searchbar on my App?

Tags: flutter

Hi I've managed to follow a tutorial on how to put a search bar to my app, however, I don't know how to merge my HomePage, and the search tool I've created from the tutorial. Finally, I'd like to know how to make my search list items clickable, so the person can go to the exact position of the element in other pages.

This is my HomePage with the classes of medications, and inside them, I have the items to be searched.

```
// @dart=2.17
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:farma/ansioliticos.dart';
import 'package:farma/antiistaminicos.dart';
import 'package:farma/antivirais.dart';
import 'package:farma/analgesicos.dart';
import 'package:farma/antibiotico.dart';
import 'package:farma/antifungicos.dart';
import 'package:farma/antiinflamatorio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:search_page/search_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Farmacologia Odontológica',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: const Splash(),
    );
  }
}

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  const Splash({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Splash> createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()));
    });
  }
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset('icons/Inicial.png', height: 200,width: 200,),
            const SizedBox(height: 30,),
            if (Platform.isIOS)
              const CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              )
            else
              const CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.white,
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Farmacologia Odontológica',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'fonts/OpenSans-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf',
            fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black54,
          ),
        ),
      ),



      body: Container(
        child:
        Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          ),
          Text('Classes de Medicamentos',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'fonts/Quicksand-Medium.ttf',
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              )),

          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => analgesicos(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Analgésicos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),

          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Antiinflamatorio(),
                ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Anti-inflamatórios')
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Antibioticos(),
              ),
            ),

            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Antibióticos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Antifungicos(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Antifúngicos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Antivirais(),
              ),
            ), // issue was here
            child: const Material(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Antivirais'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Antihistaminicos(),
              ),
            ), // issue was here
            child: const Material(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Anti-histamínicos'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Ansioliticos(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                 title: const Text('Ansiolíticos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),)

        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now this is the code from the tutorial that I want to merge so I can use the search functionality

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController? _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  List<String> medicamentosListOnSearch = [];
  List<String> medicamentosList = [
    'Ácido acetilsalicílico',
    'Dipirona sodica',
    'Paracetamol',
    'Tylex - Paracetamol + Fosfato de codeína',
    'Tramal',
    'Ibuprofeno',
    'Diclofenaco de sódio',
    'Piroxican',
    'Nimesulida',
    'Etoricoxibe',
    'Dexametasona',
    'Betametasona',
    'Acetonida de triancinolona',
    'Amoxicilina',
    'Amoxicilina + Clavulanato de potássio',
    'Ampicilina',
    'Benzetacil',
    'Cefalexina',
    'Ampicilina',
    'Azitromicina',
    'Eritromicina',
    'Claritromicina',
    'Clindamicina',
    'Metronidazol',
    'Digluconato de clorexidina 0,12%',
    'Nistatina',
    'Miconazol',
    'Cetoconazol',
    'Fluconazol',
    'Itraconazol',
    'Aciclovir',
    'Epinefrina',
    'Prometazina',
    'Diazepam',
    'Midazolam',
    'Alprazolam',
  ];
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white70,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value){
                   setState ((){
                     medicamentosListOnSearch = medicamentosList
                         .where((element) => element.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
                         .toList();
                   });
                  },
                  controller: _textEditingController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      hintText: 'Busca'
                  ),
                ),
                ),
actions: [
  TextButton(onPressed: () {
    medicamentosListOnSearch.clear();
    _textEditingController!.clear();
    setState (() {
      _textEditingController!.text = '';
    });
  },
    child: Icon (
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
    ),
  )
],
      ),

body: _textEditingController!.text.isNotEmpty && medicamentosListOnSearch.isEmpty
    ?    Center(
      child: Column( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.search_off_rounded,
            size: 60,
          color: Colors.deepOrange,),
          Text('Nenhum resultado encontrado!', style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),),
        ],
      ),
    )
    : ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _textEditingController!.text.isNotEmpty
        ? medicamentosListOnSearch.length
        : medicamentosList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          child: Icon(Icons.local_pharmacy_rounded),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10,),
        Text(
          _textEditingController!.text.isNotEmpty
              ? medicamentosListOnSearch [index]
              : medicamentosList[index],
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
      ],
    ),
  );
}
),
      );
     }
}
```

Comment: You can try it yourself, if you find any errors, update the post with min code that reproduces the error.   These types of questions don't belong here.

Comment: I have managed to paste both codes in the same tab, however, my search bar Class overlapped my HomePage Class. Only the search part is shown. I want to make the search bar visible while the medication classes are displayed below. There is no error other than a message saying my "The declaration '_HomePageState' isn't referenced."